How to get the full Sales by Product/Service Detail Report using QuickBooks API?
I have the below Python code trying to get Sales by Product/Service Detail Report data.
Under the documentation: https://developer.intuit.com/app/developer/qbo/docs/api/accounting/report-entities/SalesByProduct
It looks like the end point is going to be [ItemSales] even though the end point for the API documentation is [SalesByProduct] which is confusing.
How can I change the code below to be able to pull all the default metrics:

Product/Service
Date
Transaction type
Num
Customer name
Memo/Description
Qty
Rate
Amount
Balance

I attached a screenshot of how the report looks like under QuickBooks UI when I run the Sales by Product/Service Detail report.
Also, I want to be able to pull all the data, currently I only get 96 object but when I run my report via the UI I get 2315 rows. is there a pagination mechanism within reports API? if so, how can I implement it?
Note: When I run the report under the UI, I don't use any value for the grouping in order to see to get the data at the item line level, does that mean I should not use [summarize_column_by] attribute
def fetch_sales_by_product(access_token):

  url = f'https://quickbooks.api.intuit.com/v3/company/11111111111/reports/ItemSales' 
  headers = {
    'Authorization': f'Bearer {access_token}',
    'Accept': 'application/json'
  }

  params = {
    'start_date': '2021-01-01',
    'end_date': '2024-04-01',
    'summarize_column_by': 'ProductsAndServices'
  }

  all_data = []
  counter = 1

  while True:
    response = requests.get(url, headers=headers, params=params)
    print(f"{response.status_code=}")
    if response.status_code != 200:
      raise Exception(f"Failed to fetch report: {response.text}" )
    data = response.json()
    all_data.extend(data['Rows']['Row'])
    counter += 1

  return all_data



I can see that in your while loop you don't change the start_date or end_date variable, meaning you are asking for the same data over and over again. I can also see that you will never reach return all_data, due to the while loop being True.

@oddaspa Yes. That was just a starting point. There will be few options including pulling one day at a time or giving a date range and I assume there will be a pagination variable inside the output that I'll check and pass back to the request to get the next set of data until the return data is empty

it states here that constructing the authentication string outside of a custom authentication class may lead to unexpected behavior, have you tried the solution mentioned in this page?
